# how to fix structured data testing tool author A value for the author field is required

Tags: blogger

Author A value for the author field is required.

Hello,can anyone help me?I'm newbie in blogger...I need help how to fix this

author A value for the author field is required

Comment: Please post your code as text, not an image.

Answer (score 0):

To resolve this issue, the simple way is to go into Layout Tab  edit the Blog gadget  check the Author box present in the Post Page Options

[image: enable author display on posts]

If this doesn't work, then the 3rd party theme that you are using probably has disabled this functionality. In that case, you will have to manually add the following code inside `<b:includable id='post' var='post'>`  -

```
<span class='fn' itemprop='author' itemscope='itemscope' itemtype='http://schema.org/Person'>
  <meta expr:content='data:post.author' itemprop='name'/>
</span>
```

**Note:** Make sure to add it inside the element to which you have assigned the schema of **BlogPosting**

Answer (score 0):

you have to add codes in your page with the requested fields
eg:

```
<h1 itemprop="headline">Headline</h1>
<div itemprop="datePublished">2018-04-29 18:32:50</div>
```